# Get data from LINQ and save in array as public

Tags: c#, winforms

I want run a LINQ query to get data and save in array (or other way) 
when form loads I want to run a LINQ query to filter record from array or local data.

***Code example:***

```cs
var xbarcode = db.spProductSearch().Where(j => j.Barcode == txtbarcode.Text).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: `var arr = db.spProductSearch.Where(j => j.Barcode == txtbarcode.Text).ToArray();`? Or just `db.spProductSearch.ToArray()` if you want to filter later. Is that what you mean? Side note: why are you calling `spProductSearch` like a method? I'm assuming it's a property.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please format your code in questions using code blocks to make it easier to read. I have suggested an edit for you.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, I assume Sajid is calling stored procedure `db.spProductSearch()`.